# How to allow mail through iptables?

Tags: iptables

I'm securing my server (with iptables) so that only http and ssh ports are open and that is fine, although I use the `mail` command (server: CentOS 6.2) in some applications and it does not get through now thanks to iptables blocking everything.

What ports do I allow it access to?

Mail usage: `echo "{{message}}" | mail -s "{{subject}}" me@mail.com`

I've tried the standard mail port 25, but I have had no success with that.
Here is the current setup:

```
iptables --flush

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

# incoming ssh
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 

# outgoing ssh 
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 

#HTTP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 

# mail (does not work)
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

**(EDIT) ANSWER: The working iptables rule:**

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `OUTPUT` commands should also refer to `--dport`, not `--sport`.  You'll also want to allow `NEW` outgoing packets in order to initiate the connection to the SMTP server.

In general, however, since `OUTPUT` controls only those packets that your own system generates, you can set the `OUTPUT` policy to `ACCEPT` unless you need to prevent the *generation* of outgoing packets.

---

Two more comments:

**1.** Jay D's suggestion to "allow everything and then start blocking specific traffic" is insecure.  *Never* configure `iptables` this way because you'd have to know in advance which ports an attacker might use and block them all individually. *Always* use a whitelist instead of a blacklist if you can.

**2.** A hint from the trenches: when you're debugging `iptables`, it's often helpful to `-I`nsert and `-A`ppend log messages at the beginning and end of each chain, then clear the counters, and run an experiment. (In your case, issue the `mail` command.) Then check the counters and logs to understand how the packet(s) migrated through the chains and where they may have been dropped.

Comment: AH Yes, Thank you. I think I'll allow all OUTPUT as well.

Comment: There are two ways of doing it : 1. As u e doing block everything and then start punching holes for specific protocol traffic. 2. Allow everything And then start blocking pecific traffic. I strongly believe 1. Is a better strategy.

Comment: @JayD: Forgive the bluntness, but #1 is not simply "a better strategy" than #2; #2 is insecure to the point of negligence.  Don't _ever_ recommend this method for anything other than a learning exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments. Yes I don't quite know why anyone would use a whitelist for this type of idea. Didn't know about the log messages - that's a neat little trick.